# MYSQL Join Statement - Optional Tables?

Tags: php, mysql, join

OKay, I will try to make this make sense lol. Basically I have 4 different tables I am trying to join instead of doing a few separate SQL statements, as the MYSQL engine should be able to optimize it better than I could.

Basically I have these 4 tables:

```
projects (key:id)
project_users (key:project_id , user_id)
users (key:id)
tasks (key:project_id)
```

This is my query:

```
     SELECT projects.*, users.*, tasks.*,
     FROM 
     projects JOIN ( project_users JOIN 
                     users ON 
                     project_users.user = users.id ) 
        ON projects.id = project_users.project_id
        JOIN ( tasks )
               ON projects.id = tasks.project_id 
      WHERE projects.company = 2 ORDER BY projects.id
```

Basically I am trying to get a list of projects, users in that project, and tasks in that project for a certain company.

**THE ISSUE - If there is not a task in this project, it doesnt return that project. Which I still need that project, just with 0 tasks for that project.**

I am new to JOIN statements, so if there is some improving I can do, PLEASE let me know!

THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP!!!!!

Comment: Ehh... I'm not a SQL junkie, but my initial thought was, if you need a list of projects and a list of tasks, that's really two queries...

Comment: Well they both are comparable by a key value. Which means instead of getting projects, and then getting a list of tasks in those projects, I want to do 1 statement so its much faster.

Comment: You mean in PHP you're going to collect the list of projects as you iterate through the query result?

Comment: I agree, splitting the work would be better, as the structure of the database suggests that users are independent on tasks, and mixing those two into one query might produce some side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is add `left outer` before the join that joins the tasks. This will get you projects even though there are no tasks.

Answer (score 0):

left or right joins are your new friends

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html